# FileNotFoundException in Android (Android Studio 1.3.2)

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I know this might seem like a question being asked before but none of the answers given before seemed to help with this again.

So, the problem is `FileNotFoundException` while trying :

```
File file = new File(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("xml/cheat_data.xml").toURI());
InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
```

or

```
InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("xml/cheat_data.xml"));
```

all show FileNotFoundException or NullPointerException(1st case). While the file is clearly in that path. Trying absolute path also didn't help.

Note: Folder "xml" is in the android resource directory & this call was not inside any `Activity` class. Just a separate class with `public static void main()`

So did I miss something?

Comment: Do you mind giving us the absolute path? Maybe you're missing the package name (context.getPackageName())

Comment: Oh so "context" is an absolute must? even to get link to resources right? not like the conventional Java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Folder "xml" is in the android resource directory

That's not how you access Android resources. If you're using `ClassLoader` in conventional Android development, you're doing it wrong.

> this call was not inside any Activity class

Well, you are going to need some `Context`, whether that is an `Activity` or something else. Call `getResources().getXml(R.xml.cheat_data)` on a `Context` to get an `XmlPullParser` back that you can use to read in the parsed XML.

> Just a separate class with public static void main()

Classic Java development uses such a method; Android does not.

Comment: So is there any method to test classes besides `ApplicationTestCase` method. That default `ApplicationTest` class.?

Comment: @rjbaj: I am sorry, but I do not understand your comment.

Comment: oh..my bad. I was actually trying to test some classes using "public static void main" instead of having to start "Activity" or create "Context". I just want to know if this was a good idea.

Comment: @rjbaj: That is not going to work for anything that uses Android APIs, and accessing Android resources will use Android APIs. Android has [several testing tools](http://developer.android.com/tools/testing/testing-tools.html) that you might wish to consider.

Comment: thanks @CommonsWare and the person behind CommonsWare.

Comment: @rjbaj :: looks behind me:: Nope, nobody there, unless they are masquerading as a piece of furniture. :-)